# The right preposition in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> I don't trust him. My distrust **in/of** him is severe.

Which one is the right preposition: in or of?

Answer (score 1):

of.  "My distrust of him is severe".

You have trust in someone, but you have distrust of someone.

Comment: Do you have a source to make this answer more definitive?

Comment: This has several examples: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distrust

Comment: Please can you add this into your answer as well as adding the actual examples?